# Mice that are eating through the boards under kitchen cabinets

Tags: cabinets

I have lots of mice I. My home it ate through the board under the kitchen cabinets. How can I cover that and what do I cover it with and does peppermint oil work if I spray it around the house. Please help

Comment: If you live in an area that has a lot of mice in the environment, you are going to struggle. If you have pets or children in the home, then you must protect the traps.  Where is this?

Comment: You will not be able to stop mice from getting in.  You must deal with the mice problem first via extermination.

Comment: Get a few ratzappers, they work great.  Add a small piece of dog food, wait, zap, dump, repeat.

Answer (score 3):

#### Get Professional help.

@TheEvilGreebo is correct. I have my own mice stories which I won't bore you all with. But the bottom line is that a good exterminator can do a combination of:

- traps
- poisoned bait (they eat and (hopefully) die elsewhere
- figure out where/how the mice are getting in and either block them or tell you how to block them

The last item is particularly important. Mice can get in through a surprisingly small hole. It could be you have holes from rotting wood or recent construction and when one mouse gets in and finds food, he tells his friends...

There are plenty of "home remedies" but once you are infested, I highly recommend professional help to get the problem under control. Once it is under control, the home remedies may be sufficient.

Or (seriously) [get a cat](http://how-to-get-rid-of-mice.com/mouse-deterrent-cat/).

Comment: You'll need to stay vigilant with the traps and/or bait for months, if not years.  As long as there's at least one breeding pair surviving, you won't see the end of the mice.  Definitely talk to a professional to make a plan.  Try to find someone who deals regularly with rodents.  There are some pros who only do insect control, and they won't be helpful.  Search for "rodent control" or "wildlife control" in your area.

Comment: If you want to plug the holes yourself, search online for "copper mesh for rodent control" and buy some.  Stuff a piece in each hole, then saturate it with expanding foam to hold it in place.  That will create a good barrier to keep the mice from chewing through in the same place again.  Keep in mind that they'll still find other places to chew through, but it's still worth doing because you'll keep them confined (hopefully near traps and/or bait) for a while.